# Kubuntu 18.04: How do I control SD Card auto-mount directory and permissions?

Tags: mount, automount, sd-card

When I insert an SD card, it auto-mounts at `/media/user/label` with the user as the owner and root as the group.

I would like it to auto-mount in a non-user-specific place, say `/media` or `/mnt`, ideally with a different group so that I can allow other users to access it.

If I make a directory at `/media/user/label` and `chown` it, that is ignored and the SD card mounts at `/media/user/label1`.

I mostly leave the same SD card in all the time for first-line backup purposes, which is why I need other users to be able to access the mount point, but occasionally I eject it and put another SD card in temporarily for other purposes, so I don't want to put it in fstab.

I have found the Kubuntu Systems Settings which allow you to change whether it auto-mounts, but it does not allow you to specify where it automounts or with what permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, [this stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612158/change-the-name-of-the-mountpoint-used-by-udisks2) pointed me to [this piece of udisks source code](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c#L638), which shows the mount point is hard coded!